# Double surface in the pressure temperature concentration curve for a binary mixture

Tags: thermodynamics, vapor-pressure, distillation, chemical-engineering

[image]

In the 3 dimensional diagram given, when a constant pressure plane intersects with the double surface, it produces a looped curve without a maxima or minima. What is the double surface and how is the looped curve produced? And since the line joining $T_\ce{A}$ and $C_\ce{A}$ is the temperature-pressure curve of pure A and similarly for B, I cannot understand what the curve joining the 2 critical points (of A and B) means.

Answer (score 2):

The liquid phase is above the surface. The vapor phase is below the surface.

The planar cut at a constant temperature is easiest to understand. The bottom curve will show the composition of the liquid phase as a function of molar fraction, and the upper curve will show the composition of the vapor phase.

Likewise for the curves of molar fraction versus temperature at a given pressure.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.. And what about the curve linking the 2 critical points ? Does that curve mean that critical pressure of component A has exceeded and now it has become a single phase ?